# WinForms - implementing a text control with alt+shift column selection

Tags: c#, winforms, selection, text-editor

Please forgive me a slightly broad question,

Is there a standard / canonical way to implement alt+shift rectangular / column / block text selection in a WinForms application? For example similar to Notepad++ or Visual Studio.

I noticed an occasional tool supports such selection and was wondering if it's implemented from scratch every time? Hopefully not, seeing as these seem to be compatible with each other most of the time. On the other hand, I cannot find much on implementing such behaviour, or the format of "column-selected-text" object.

Last thing I can think of is try to look how it's implemented in notepad++ / visual studio code source, but was hoping to find a minimal example or a tutorial.

Language is not too important but tagged C# as a personal preference.

Comment: No there is not such functionality in the standard textbox. Wherever you see it, it has been written from scratch.

Comment: But how do you make it compatible across different tools that support this?

Comment: What do you mean with 'compatible'?

Comment: You can copy such selection across applications and keep the "blockiness" and not insert line breaks like you would if you copied regular paragraph of text.

Comment: Yes but it is the receiving application that has itself the 'block mode' active and interprets the text on the clipboard in the correct mode. If the receiving application is not in block mode the text will be copied wrongly. (unless the two applications agrees on some kind of not well documented clipboard format)